# How to find text in Word, insert additional values before text with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

I'm entirely new to VBA. I need to write a macro to do as the following pseudo code describes. Any references to VBA code are from looking at examples I've found so far from googling. Many thanks for any guidance you can offer.

```
Dim myText as string;
Dim myAutoTextFieldValue as string;
Set myText='Figure';
Set myAutoTextFieldValue = 'fignum';
     // fignum is a autotext value that will insert a sequence type field

.Find text which matches this Word expression \[[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]\]
     // this expression works in the Find what function in Word, not strictly regex

For each
.InsertBefore (myText + myTextAutoFieldValue);
     // I'm guessing I'll need a With expression and a Do While.
```

**EDIT:**

I now have the following but I get "Method or Data Member not found" when I try to run it.

```
Sub EditFindLoop()
'find text where the string equals [00:00:00] or numeric sequence as per input mask
'then insert myText and myAutoTextFieldValue before it
Dim myText As String
Dim myAutoTextFieldValue As String
Dim myFind As String
myFind = "\[[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]\]"
myAutoTextFieldValue = "fignum"
myText = "Figure"
    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        '.Text = myFind
        '.ClearFormatting
        .MatchWildcards = True
        Do While .Execute(findText:=myFind, Forward:=True) = True
                    .InsertBefore myText & myAutoTextFieldValue
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a teaching site, or a place where people write code for you. It's a place to ask targeted questions about specific problems you're having with code you're writing. There are sites where teaching is encouraged and people provide code for you - try the Microsoft Communities (Answers) or Word for Developers on MSDN. In an Internet search you'll find TONS of code samples for doing wildcard searches in Word with "interruptions" for performing actions. But please note that you probably don't even need any VBA code as Word's REPLACE functionality could do what you're looking for.

Comment: @CindyMeister I do need VBA. If Word's REPLACE function had what I needed, I wouldn't be asking here. I'm not lazy, I did my homework testing out what I was trying to do without resorting to VBA first.

Answer (score 2):

And here's the answer to my own question, should anyone else require a similar piece of code.

```
Sub EditFindLoop()
    Dim myText As String
    Dim myFind As String
    Dim x As Integer
    myFind = "\[[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]\]"
    myText = "Figure "
    mySpace = ". "
    x = 1
    Dim oRange As Word.Range
    Set oRange = ActiveDocument.Range

    With oRange.Find
        .Text = myFind
        .ClearFormatting
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False

        Do While .Execute = True
            If .Found Then
                oRange.InsertBefore (myText & x & mySpace)
            End If
            oRange.Start = oRange.End
            oRange.End = ActiveDocument.Range.End
            x = x + 1
        Loop
    End With

End Sub
```